Using a git tool NuGet package as a code dependency?
I'd like to write a .Net library and pack it into a NuGet package. This library requires external executables to work. Specifically, it runs git commands to manage some files in a local repository.
There is a NuGet package which almost seems to be what I'm looking for: Git-Windows-Minimal. It's just a MinGit package. Unfortunately, git is treated as a development tool, not as a dependency for my code to use.
Is there a way to set up my .Net project to use these tools from code? When someone uses my library's NuGet package, the git executables would need to be included among their build output as well, of course.
